# Can I extend a typescript interface to put all keys under a new key?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an existing Typescript interface like this:

```
interface Person {
 name: string;
 age: number;
 pet: string;
}
```

Another method (out of my control) requires the input to have each value be placed in an object `{value: value}` like this:

```
update({
   name: {value: "string"},
   age: {value: 0},
   pet: {value: "dog"}
})
```

Is there some way to extend or make use of my existing `Person` interface to create a new `type` or `interface` to match that required format?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work:

```
interface Person {
 name: string;
 age: number;
 pet: string;
}

type AwkwardPerson = {
    [K in keyof Person]: { value: Person[K] }
}

let newTyped: AwkwardPerson = {
   name: {value: "string"},
   age: {value: 0},
   pet: {value: "dog"}
}
```

We iterate over the keys of person and give the desired shape with the right type.

If you have a lot of those interfaces going on that you need to convert, you can make a generic converter (instead of repeating yourself) like this:

```
type MakeAwkward<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: { value: T[key] }
}

type GenericAwkwardPerson = MakeAwkward<Person>

let genericTyped: GenericAwkwardPerson = {
   name: {value: "string"},
   age: {value: 0},
   pet: {value: "dog"}
}
```

Any interface you give to MakeAwkward<> inside the angled brackets will be converted to a compatible type.

Comment: Thanks, @RestOfTheBothWorlds, I'm seeing an error `'Person' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

Comment: Hmm this works in the playground with strict mode, maybe you have something different? See: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EXPZcQK6kBG0zyABwhgqNOiCYEAvgQJgAnkOQBZOAGsIAQQDua7XCgATADwAVAHzIAvPiLJ7AbQ3zkoZM6wxkpgLpU8yABucAA2HOymThDyPsgyMnKKKADiECDQwAg6egaG6FDYuDaqGtn6Rsb5heayIcLIbOl0CKZJhlSpTZlluVU41rb2xGTseMFh7ABEYgyTUgA0dsiso+PhVAAMC0tCIvhrU4ZY9HPSQA)